# How calculate a circumscribing circle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

A little while ago, I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3298162/is-clarkes-astronautical-geometry-wrong-solving-triangles) and received what looks to be a decent answer. Now I'm coming back to this and want to try to implement it. Given the following:

[image]

S, V, X and E are points on a 2D plane. I want to calculate the circumcentre and radius of the two circles (so I can calculate their intersections to determine the positions of X). The difficult is that for each triangle SVX and XES I know only one angle and one line - A and B are known and the SV line and SE line are known. Given that information only, I can't figure out how to calculate the circles with my barely remembered high school math.

If someone could point me in the right direction to do this, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need more information. Given a chord and the central angle it subtends, there are two possible circles.

Comment: @amd why do you say that? I haven't found time to work through a problem yet, but the answer given below looks pretty solid?

Comment: How do you know that the unknown point $X$ is “above” $SE$ instead of “below” it?

Comment: @amd let me come back to you when I've time to figure this out; sorry (math is not my strong suit, that's what computers are for. Doesn't help when you don't remember how it's meant to work though, I'll never slate high-school math as pointless again!!)

Comment: @amd ok so; there are two possible circles (and two possible triangles) for the ESX problem,and ditto for the VSX triangle. However, only the "correct" solution has one circle from each problem intersecting at both S and X. So it gets more complicated (having to solve for all of the possibilities) but it's still possible, I think.

Comment: @amd Nah you're right. A swift mock up in GeoGebra suggests min 3 points where the angles all fit.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** I originally misread the question to think that $X$'s position was known. However, there's not enough information to determine the position of $X$ uniquely. Instead, it could be as shown below, or it could instead be this point reflected in the line $SE$. Further details about this issue, as well as using an alternate algebraic method, are explained in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3575373/602049). If you can determine which $X$ point you want, then you can use the method shown below to determine the corresponding circle.

[image: Circle with inscribed angle]

You can use that the [inscribed angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle) is half of the central angle that subtends the same arc in the circle, such as shown in the diagram above, and on the right side of the linked Wikipedia article. For example, with $SE$, you have that if $O$ is the center of the circle that both points are on, then $\angle SOE = 2B$. Let $M$ be the midpoint of $SE$. Thus, by drawing the perpendicular bisector of $SE$, it goes through $M$ and $O$, with it splitting the angle at $O$ in half, as shown. Thus, you have $\tan B = \frac{|SM|}{|MO|} \implies |MO| = \frac{|SM|}{\tan B}$. You can thus determine the perpendicular bisector line and use this length to determine where the center of the circle is.

To get the circle radius, call it $r$, note it's given by $r = \frac{|SM|}{\sin B}$. Also, you can use basically the same procedure for the other circle to get its corresponding values.

I'll leave it to you to set up the appropriate equations for the various lines and their lengths to get the coordinates of $O$, as well as those of the center of the other circle.

Comment: Hi @JohnOmielan. Thanks for the answer. As amd points out, there are 2 possible triangles in a 2D plan where the measured angle fits; X can be mirrored on the SE line. This results in two different circles, and drawing all 4 circles (including the 2 from the VEX triangle) results in at least 3 intersections where the angles all work out. So, this doesn't quite work unfortunately. Any ideas?

Comment: @DanScally You're welcome for the answer, and sorry for misreading your question. I thought you had the position for $X$ already. However, with just the information you have, i.e., the chord & the inscribed angle, then as you stated, $X$ can be mirrored in the $SE$ line. Without any more information, I don't see how you can narrow it down to which one is correct. Since my answer doesn't really answer your question, I'll delete it fairly shortly after I've confirmed you've been online &, I assume, have read this comment.

Comment: @DanScally Since the other answer references this one as being an easier one to use than it's algebraic method using vectors, I've decided to instead give an update statement at the beginning to indicate the incomplete nature of my answer in answering your question.

Comment: Thanks - forgot to comment to say I'd seen your response last night. And still thanks for the answer; despite being incomplete I still found it very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you don’t have enough information for a unique solution. Knowing only the endpoints of the arc and the inscribed angle, there are two possible arcs. You basically need to know which side of the chord’s extension the unknown point $X$ lies on in order to disambiguate them.

Algebraically, if you have the endpoiints $\mathbf p_1=(x_1,y_1)$ and $\mathbf p_2=(x_2,y_2)$ and the inscribed angle $\alpha$, then the two arcs are described by the equation $$(x-x_1)(x-x_2)+(y-y_1)(y-y_2)=\sqrt{(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2}\sqrt{(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2}\cos\alpha.\tag{*}$$ This equation is simply the formula for the dot product of two vectors, rearranged slightly. Applied to your example, this produces something like the following illustration:

[image: intersecting double arcs]

The point $X$ that you’re trying to find is one of the intersections of the blue and red double arcs, but there is another (besides the point $S$ itself, of course).

Note, too, that if you square the above equation in order to eliminate the radicals to make solving the system of equations easier, you introduce even more spurious solutions: squaring the equation adds the complementary arcs to the solution set, so the equation is now that of two complete circles. The additional arcs are indicated by dashed lines below:

[image]

In this case, squaring introduces two more intersections.

As a practical matter, instead of working with equation (*), I think it will be easier to work out the centers and radii of the four circles using the inscribed angle theorem†, as described in another answer, compute pairwise intersections, which reduces to computing some line-circle intersections, and then discard potential solutions based on whatever other criteria you might have.

---

† Let $d$ be half the chord length. Then, the two circle centers lie on the chord’s perpendicular bisector at a distance of $d/\tan\alpha$ from its intersection with the chord.